# How to check is any thread waiting on condition variable?

Tags: java, locks, concurrency

I have Condition variable named cond.

Is there any method which could give me true or false if there is any thread awaiting on cond?

I need something like:
        Boolean cond.isAwaitingSetEmpty()

Thanks for help

Comment: I would suspect this is an X-Y problem and that a trip to [Lock Objects](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) is in order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "condition" you mean a `Condition` created by `ReentrantLock.newCondition()`, then you can use [`ReentrantLock.hasWaiters(Condition cond)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html).

Comment: well it gives `IllegalMonitorStateException`

Answer (score 0):

It's available from the `Lock` that the `Condition` is bound to:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

For example:

```
getWaitingThreads(Condition condition) 
getWaitQueueLength(Condition condition)
```

etc.