# How to check is any thread waiting on condition variable boost conditional variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

How to check if there is any thread waiting on condition variable boost conditional variable?

i.e. Is there an equivalent to this [How to check is any thread waiting on condition variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998609/how-to-check-is-any-thread-waiting-on-condition-variable) in boost c++ ?

I have already checked the documentation but I could not find something useful.

Comment: [The `boost::condition_variable` class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.condition_variable) exposes no such functionality, so the answer has to be no.

Comment: If documentation is not explayn something you can inspect source code but founded solution may not be worked in future. Possible solution make a wrapper for condition variable with needed functional and use it.

Comment: Is there anyway to come around this? is there a class that provides similar functionality and having this function? e.g. can asio be helpful?

Comment: It should be possible to make a wrapper-class that encapsulates `boost::condition_variable` and have an atomic boolean flag set when waiting. Then you could check this flag.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You need a counter, not a bool - there be be several waiters to keep track of